# biomesyncd takes 100% of CPU

Tags: macos

I recently changed the battery on my Macbookpro A1990 and updated to Monterey 12.4. Since then, my Mac started running periodically every ~20min the process `biomesyncd` that takes 100% of the CPU, activating the fan and overheating the machine.

I've to stop it from `Activity Monitor` or use `kill -9` but sometimes the process continuously restarts until I've to restart the pc. Makes my Macbook unusable.

I've tried to remove the executable with `sudo` but is protected by MacOS. I opened a report to Apple but I don't know what to do, since I need to use my Mac. I also reset the PRAM but nothing.

Do you know how can I prevent this process from starting? Or override the MacOS protection and remove the executable?

Comment: i found a thread saying deleting `~/Library/biome` fixed it.

Comment: You saved my Mac to be thrown out of the window! Thanks :)

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer. I don't need the points & all I can claim is a bit of google-fu, from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253603115

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me today, it was 100% after I reconfigured Spotlight and it was reindexing the library. After few minutes, it is gone.